# Problemas con JasperReport y PHP

Tags: php, jasper

Estoy haciendo reportes con JasperReport y lo estoy haciendo correr en PHP con una librería que encontré en GitHub y se llama "jrs-rest-php-client-2.0.0", probé y todo bien genera los reportes pero solo con los parámetros establecidos en el SQL y que cuando quiero calcular por ejemplo un parámetro que si tiene X valor imprimí 0 o si viene con X imprimí 1 no funciona.

Ejemplo de una variable: `$F{tipo_donante}.compareTo( "persona") == 0 ? "X": ""`

Adjunto imagen de de ambos uno en el JasperSoft y otro en el PDF en la aplicación.
Gracias.

Dentro del Jasper

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el PDF de la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues, uno podría revisar la [documentación](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/php-client-sample-code) y ver qué pasa cuando intentas generar el reporte, pero sin algo más de código que nos muestre cómo generas el reporte, es difícil (PHP no es algo que use a diario pero me gustaría intentar ayudar :) ). Considera [edit] la pregunta y añadir más info

Comment: Lo estoy solucionando con un case when en dentro del SQL, Gracias!

Comment: Bueno, si encontraste un workaround o algo, considera ponerlo como respuesta. Vas a recibir los votos positivos y vas a ayudar a otros en el futuro con el mismo problema!

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione con un CASE WHEN dentro del SQL:

```
SELECT
donante.per_jur_donan_id, 
donante.per_jur_apellido, 
case when donante.nro_jur_ci <> '' then 'X' else '' end nro_jur_ci , 
case when donante.per_jur_ruc <> '' then 'X' else '' end per_jur_ruc,
donante.per_jur_cel, 
donante.per_jur_direccion, 
distritos.distri_nombre, 
departamentos.dpto_nombre, 
donante.per_jur_correo, 
donante.solicitud_incripcion_firmada,
case when donante.fotocopia_ci <> '' then 'X' else '' end fotocopia_ci ,
donante.documento_legal_org, 
donante.acta_ultima_asamblea, 
case when donante.tipo_donante = 'org' then per_jur_ruc else  nro_jur_ci end tipo_donante, 
donante.fecha_add, 
donante.localidad
FROM
donante
INNER JOIN
distritos
ON 
    donante.per_jur_distrito = distritos.distri_id
INNER JOIN
departamentos
ON 
    donante.per_jur_dpto = departamentos.dpto_id
WHERE 
 donante.per_jur_donan_id =  $P{id_donante}
```

Esas condiciones validan campos vacíos ya que guarda el nombre de los documentos subidos y no el binario; si se presentó documentos esos campos no estarán vacíos y en el reporte debe marcar con una "X" en el check y el otro caso tengo un checkbox donde valido el tipo de persona (si es persona física tiene como valor "persona" y si es una organización es "org"). Saludos.